# Change state in popup button

Tags: leaflet, react

I have a state called modal which by default is false and im trying to change the state with a button inside the popup but its stays false

[image: button]

```
 import { MapContainer, GeoJSON, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
 import "./Map.css";
 import { useState } from "react";

const Map = (props) => {
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
const [center, setCenter] = useState([50.832915, -3.146892]);
const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(2);

const countryStyle = {
fillColor: "#A7BEAE",
color: "white",
weight: 0.2,
fillOpacity: 1,
};

function getHandlerForFeature(feat) {
return function (e) {
  setModal(true);
};
}

     const onEachCountry = (country, layer) => {
const map = useMap();
const name = country.properties.ADMIN;
const population = country.properties.POPULATION;
const deaths = country.properties.DEATHS;
const cases = country.properties.CASES;
const active = country.properties.ACTIVE;
const recovered = country.properties.RECOVERED;
const lastUpdate = country.properties.LAST_UPDATE;
const flag = country.properties.FLAG;
const countryCenter = layer.getBounds().getCenter();

var popupCountryInfo = L.popup({
  closeOnClick: true,
  autoClose: true,
}).setContent(
  `
<div class="pop" >
Country:  ${name} <img src=${flag} placeholder="${name}"/>
<br/>
Population:${population}
<br/>
Cases:${cases}
<br/>
Infected:${active}
<br/>
Recovered:${recovered}
<br/>
Deaths:${deaths}
<br/>
Last Update:${lastUpdate}
<br/>
<button id='mybutton' >My button</button>
</div>`
);

layer.on({
  mouseover: (event) => {
    event.target.setStyle({
      fillColor: "#B85042",
    });
    var popupCountry = L.popup({
      closeOnClick: true,
      autoClose: true,
    })
      .setLatLng(event.latlng)
      .setContent(
        `<div>
        ${name} <img src=${flag} placeholder="${name}"/>
        <br/>
        Click country for info
        </div>`
      )
      .openOn(map);
    layer.bindPopup(popupCountryInfo);
  },
  mouseout: (event) => {
    event.target.setStyle({
      fillColor: "#A7BEAE",
    });
  },
  popupopen: (layer) => {
    L.DomEvent.on(
      document.getElementById("mybutton"),
      "click",
      getHandlerForFeature(layer)
    );
  },
  click: (event) => {
    var popupCountryInfo = event.target.getPopup();
    popupCountryInfo.setLatLng(event.latlng).openOn(map);
    layer.bindPopup(popupCountryInfo).openPopup().closePopup();
  },
});
};

return (
<>
  <div style={{ zIndex: -1 }}>
    <MapContainer
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      zoom={zoom}
      center={center}
      minZoom={2.3}
      maxZoom={6}
      scrollWheelZoom="true"
    >
      <GeoJSON
        style={countryStyle}
        data={props.countriesData}
        onEachFeature={onEachCountry}
      />
    </MapContainer>
  </div>
</>
);
};

export default Map;
```

Comment: What is `setModal`? I don't see it being defined anywhere.

Comment: set modal is below the map function is the usestate and the setmodal is below the country style in the getHandlerForFeature function

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with React and can't help you here.